# Making an unrequested change at revision stage to a journal paper

Tags: paper-submission

I had submitted a paper in a journal, and had got a request for major revision. The changes are mostly related to the experiments, and some language issues. However, while trying to fix those, I stumbled a much better (theoretical) solution to the same problem. Should I include this improved solution in the revised version? Or is it better to write this improved solution as an additional note, and let this paper go as is?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Make the improvement*

The review process is there to improve the paper. If there are things that you can do to improve the paper without the reviewers help that's great! Making the changes is helpful to everyone.

From the reviewer's point of view - there will always be comments from other reviewers which I didn't think of. I wouldn't expect all improvements to come from my comments.

From the editor's point of view - they way to publish high quality papers. The review process is one (very important) aspect of this.

From your point of view - you want your papers to be as good as possible.

Comment: Agreed. The paper belongs to the authors until they sign over rights.

Comment: Your new result requires review. It's nice if you can bump up the quality of your original paper, but you should actually have it re-reviewed whenever there is substantial new material (such as in your case). Don't forget, you may have introduced mistakes or overlooked something with the new approach.

Comment: My plan is to make a full disclosure to the editor. If the editor thinks the change is substantial enough for a re-review, she is free to suggest this. Otherwise, it might anyway go to the same reviewers with a further note.

Comment: In my experience (maths), I expect substantial revisions to re-reviewed. In recent times, this means a paper will normally go out to review at least twice.

Comment: I also think that another round of review will be consequent if the paper takes a new cut. It should be, in fact. I am a bit surprised by the answer. It really depends on what the changes are, if you tell the editor,  if s/he spots them....

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly disagree with @TomR, but - I'd say this depends on how deep the revision is, and how far along the process you are. If its fundamental enough, and the review process has been long and involved, then your new idea is essentially a different piece of research. In that situation, I would perhaps consult with the editors (or reviewers directly if relevant) about whether or not to introduce the change; or perhaps decide from the get-go that it's material for another paper, and mention the alternative method in a concluding remark, e.g. something like "The authors believe that XYZ can be improved upon using ABC."